# Why express api doesn't GET this folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a js script for a server is required to GET files from folder called "public". But when I go to localhost it says Cannot GET / .The script is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('/public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

I am really new to js, express api, and web dev in general so could anybody help me?

Comment: `'/', ` looks like it might be a typo? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: app.use('/static', express.static('public')) (I got that from the site you mentioned) you can put that in app.use but i dont know why its not working.

Comment: Are you going to `localhost`, or to `localhost:3000`?

Comment: localhost:3000 I am going

Comment: this is what it shows :: Cannot GET /

Comment: If you want to serve static files from the root use `app.use(express.static('/public'));`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Nothing has changed

Comment: @evolutionxbox there is a folder which are in same directory as app.js i want to make my script to GET request it

Comment: @Bergi i am using with port 3000

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment since I don't have the rep, but judging by your other comments you want to change the `/public` to `./public`